# Is it possible to share a directory in Windows on Parallels to the host?

Tags: windows, macos, parallels

It is possible and easy using Parallels to share a host folder from Mac into the Windows guest. However, for the workflow I desire [I need to go the other direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306834/docker-windows-to-windows-volume-on-network-drive) and share a folder from the guest onto the host.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from http://kb.parallels.com/en/122567

> **Shared Folders Tool**
>
> Shared Folders Tool enables you to share Mac folders with the virtual machine and vice versa. With this tool, you can access your Mac folders from the virtual machine and virtual machine folders from Mac OS X. You can also choose custom folders to share.
>
> Please follow the steps below to enable Shared Folders Tool:
>
> 1. Open virtual machine window (Do not click Start).
> 2. Open virtual machine configuration > switch to Options tab > Sharing.
> 3. Set Share Folders to the desired value.
> 4. Choose the Custom Folders if you need.
>
> If you want to share Windows folders with Mac check Access Windows folders from Mac and Mount virtual disks to Mac desktop in the Share Windows pane. Windows volumes will appear on the Mac Desktop.